# What should I do when reviewing an edit that provides an update to an old answer?

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits

The system presented me [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26178835) to review, repeating what seems to be a common scenario: a user that absolutely in good faith suggests an edit to an apparently outdated answer. In this specific case it was about an interface change in a tool.

Usually I skip such reviews, and I know it is the encouraged action. But I think it would be useful to understand what to  do in this cases.

In my opinion this scenario is different to:

- The case in which the users provide their alternate answer ([meta question here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/365225/11336762)). In these cases I encourage people to write their own answer.
- The case in which they update obsolete code ([meta question here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281830/11336762)). In this case I reject, unless a blatant inconsistency is fixed (and it is about something I'm proficient about).
- The case in which a dead link is edited  ([meta question here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300024/11336762)). And in this case if the link seems restored I accept unless it is related to something I'm really ignorant about.

So the question is: what to do with edits that provide an update to an answer without editing code, restoring a dead link and that might not be enough for a new answer?

Comment: Is the edit not changing the original meaning / intent of the answer and is it adding value that future visitors will value? If yes, accept, if not reject.

Comment: Improve the edit to remove the bold Edit: header. Otherwise, it's just adding a sentence. No big whoop.

Comment: @HereticMonkey well... it depends on the sentence. In this case could either be something adding value or a wrong information. Of course my doubts don't apply to additions related to topics in which I'm an expert.

Comment: If you're not an expert (or at least fluent enough to evaluate the worth of the edit) in the topic, you should probably be skipping.